# Move relative to screen

Tags: unity, 3d, camera

I use top down 60 degree tilted camera and want move always visually straight directions relative to screen (up, down, left, right). When object is near screen edges it starts moving diagonally (visually) probably because of camera tilt.

I tried with `WorldToViewportPoint` / `ViewportPointToRay` but it doesnt work exactly because even when there is no input, conversion to viewport and back to world same value sometimes gives slighltly offset from start position.

```
float delta = Time.deltaTime;

float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

Vector3 view = MainCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

view.x = (h > 0) ? 1 : (h < 0) ? 0 : view.x;
view.y = (v > 0) ? 1 : (v < 0) ? 0 : view.y;

Ray ray = MainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(view);

RaycastHit hit;

Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << 15); // 15 - ground plane layer

Vector3 world = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z);

Vector3 dir = (world - transform.position).normalized;

transform.position += dir * Speed * delta;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently trying to **transform** a camera-space vector to a world-space vector, that's one of the best use case for **matrices**! ( I may get a bit too hyped about math-related questions)

I'll be honest, if I'd say I know Unity I would lie, but I know it has a `Matrix4x4` class, and that you can create a transformation matrix with the `TRS(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)` function. Because we don't want to move or scale the vector, we can pass a `(0; 0; 0)` and a `(1; 1; 1)` vector to position and scale respectively.

`rotation` is what we care the most about. For this you'll need the angles of your camera im a `Quaternion`, which if you don't have already, you can get like the following:

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraRotation.x, cameraRotation.y, cameraRotation.z);
```

And you're almost done! Now you only need to pass these as an argument to the TRS function, then use the resulting matrix to get the world-space vector.

```
Matrix4x4 rotation = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), rotation, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
// Here I assume your camera-space vector is a 2d vector named "move"
Vector4 worldSpaceMove = rotation * new Vector4(move.x, move.y, 0, 0);
```

And worldPosMove is your world-space vector. It's a 4d vector, because you can't multiply a 4x4 matrix with a 3d vector.

Edit:

Second approach:

The current solution moves the object on a plane. Because of this, the object gets actually farther from the camera at some points. To solve this problem, you need to move it around the camera.

This is also very simple: You need to get the vector between the camera and the object, rotate it around, then you can get the new position of the object by adding the vector to the camera's position:

```
Vector3 toObject = objectPosition - camera.transform.position;
Vector4 tempVector = new Vector4(toObject.x, toObject.y, toObject.z, 0);
// Note the order of the coordinates when creating the quaternion
Matrix4x4 rotation = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(move.y, move.x, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
tempVector *= rotation;
Vector3 newPosition = camera.transform.position + new Vector3(tempVector.x, tempVector.y, tempVector.z);
```

Now set the position of the object to newPosition.

Comment: It doesnt work at all, object moves visually diagonally at screen edges. Maybe I didnt understand code correctly. `Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(MainCamera.transform.rotation.x, MainCamera.transform.rotation.y, MainCamera.transform.rotation.z);
Matrix4x4 mat = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), rot, new Vector3(1, 1, 1)); Vector4 dir = mat * new Vector4(h, 0, v, 0);
transform.position += new Vector3(dir.x, dir.y, dir.z) * Speed * delta;`

Comment: @Demion ovject move diagonally, because your camera isn't orthographic. Let me come up with another solution (that'll proably also involve matrices.

Comment: Or trigonometry

Comment: @Demion see edit

Comment: Still not as good (not straight at screen edges) as moving in screen / viewport coordinates and then convert back to world I used in my initial question. Problem is with this conversion back and forth I get offsets even without input converting same value. I used `Quaternion.Euler(-v, 0, h)`

Comment: @Demion that's probably the best you get.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I made workaround to make it look move pretty straight. If anyone has more reliable and correct solution I will accept answer. Plane / box collider at layer 8.

```
float delta = Time.deltaTime;

float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

Vector3 screen = MainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

Vector3 move = screen + new Vector3(h, v, 0);

Ray ray = MainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(screen);

RaycastHit hit;

Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << 8);

Vector3 world = hit.point;

ray = MainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(move);

Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << 8);

Vector3 dir = (hit.point - world).normalized;

transform.position += dir * Speed * delta;
```